# Microsoft SharePoint 2013 Certification:confusing question

Tags: certification

You plan to create a workflow design by using Microsoft Visio 2013 and then import the design into SharePoint Designer 2013.
You need to ensure that you have repetition capability. Which shape should you use?

```
A. Stage 
B. Assign a Task 
C. Step 
D. Loop
```

What is the correct answer for this?

loop or stage?
 please share your view

Answer (score 0):

It should be Loop, given the need to support repetition

> Loops are a series of connected shapes that will execute as a loop,
>   returning from the last shape in the series to the first, until a
>   condition is satisfied.

Read more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj163272)